# How do I create a list to store strings in java applet

Tags: java, list, applet

I am trying to create a list that holds all the strings inputted by the user. I'm not sure if the code below is the right way to create a string, however, I created the list of strings, a string called x which will be assigned to textf to retrieve the user input but nothing happens when I press the button. I wanted to make sure that the code below is the right way to add the user input into a secret stored list when they press the button "b1"

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.ArrayList; 
import java.util.List;

public class test 1 extends Applet implements ActionListener {

List<String> wordList = new ArrayList <String>();
Font fonttext;
TextField textf;
String x; 
Button b1;
Button b2;
Button b3;
Button b4;
Button b5;
Button b6;

public void init(){
    setBackground(Color.lightGray); 
    fonttext = new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 24);

    textf = new TextField("", 40);

    add(textf);
    b1 = new Button ("Add word to list");
    b2 = new Button ("Display words from list with that letter");
    b3 = new Button ("Search list for this word(show occurence)");
    b4 = new Button ("Remove first occurence of this word");
    b5 = new Button ("Remove all occurence of this word");
    b6 = new Button ("Clear the list ");

     b1.addActionListener(this);
     b2.addActionListener(this);
     b3.addActionListener(this);
     b4.addActionListener(this);
     b5.addActionListener(this);
     b6.addActionListener(this);

     add(b1);
     add(b2);
     add(b3);
     add(b4);
     add(b5);
     add(b6);
}

public void paint(Graphics g){
    this.b1.setLocation(20,600);
    this.b2.setLocation(150,600);
    this.b3.setLocation(400,600);
    this.b4.setLocation(680,600);
    this.b5.setLocation(930,600);
    this.b6.setLocation(1170,600);

}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    if (e.getSource() == b1 ){
        x = textf.getText();
        wordList.add(x);
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Seems correct.. In order to figure out what's wrong, we'd need to see your actual, complete code.

Comment: alright i'll post the whole code

Comment: What are you doing in `paint(` ?

Comment: Seems like those methods are for setting the on-screen location of the buttons, @Tim

Comment: setting the location of the six buttons

Comment: @JonasCz In `paint(`? It was rhetorical question/expression of concern/whatever rather than a real question. I can rephrase it to say "why are you doing that in `paint`?" and more to the point "why are you doing that at all not using a layout manager?"...or even...why is he using AWT not Swing?

Comment: i'm only a beginner at java so i'm not really sure how to use another method

Comment: @Tim, I understand. I don't know anything about java applets though, so excuse my ignorance :-)

Comment: How do you know that nothing happens? Your event handler adds something to the list, but how do you expect to be able to see that? You are not doing anything with the list.

Comment: yeah I just figured that, basically I want to now just test it by clicking on b2 to show on the screen what words are in the list currently, to see if it actually works

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/start/